# SSIS Error - ODBC Source

Tags: mysql, sql-server, odbc, ssis

I am using ODBC connection to connect to MYSQL in SSIS - the connection is successful, but when the SSIS package is executed, I get the below error.

`[ODBC Source [30]] Error: SQLSTATE: 22018, Message: [MySQL][ODBC 8.0(a) Driver][mysqld-5.7.30-0ubuntu0.16.04.1];  [ODBC Source [30]] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_INDUCEDTRANSFORMFAILUREONERROR.  The "ODBC Source.Outputs[ODBC Source Output]" failed because error code 0xC020F450 occurred, and the error row disposition on "ODBC Source" specifies failure on error. An error occurred on the specified object of the specified component.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.`

`[SSIS.Pipeline] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PRIMEOUTPUTFAILED.  The PrimeOutput method on ODBC Source returned error code 0xC0209029.  The component returned a failure code when the pipeline engine called PrimeOutput(). The meaning of the failure code is defined by the component, but the error is fatal and the pipeline stopped executing.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.`

I looked online for the solutions, but nothing worked. I have done enoough investigation but no use.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30810699/ssis-error-code-dts-e-inducedtransformfailureonerror and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16544997/dts-e-primeoutputfailed-with-error-code-0xc0202091-when-loading-flat-file

Comment: @spikey_richie The both links you have mentioned are not related sorry. The error I get doesn't specify any column details, also the ODBC source is a SQL command that gets data from MYSQL

Comment: Seems like a data error. It can be many things: Incompatible data format, null in not-null field, incompatible SQL versions between client and server. Not enough info here for a better idea.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why I got this error, But the error resolved -- In the source --> Error output, I selected Ignore Failure for the columns